# windows client can't join samba domain anymore

Tags: linux, active-directory, domain, samba

**DISCLAMER:**
I'm still trying to fully learn and understand how to properly maintain a samba domain controller.

**The Problem:**

I had a working samba installation with AD controlle but now, just a month after my last computer join, it won't work anymore. On Windows it says "unknown user or password" but I've checked them to be correct.

I tried setting the log level to 3 in "smb.conf" and while trying to join a computer this gets logged:

```
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.018256,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ admuser@example.net from ipv4:172.27.2.58:50124 for krbtgt/example.net@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.039839,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: 128
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.040080,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.040191,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.040341,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: No preauth found, returning PREAUTH-REQUIRED -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.043598,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.054880,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ admuser@example.net from ipv4:172.27.2.58:50125 for krbtgt/example.net@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.076255,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: encrypted-timestamp, 128
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.076483,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.076587,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.077527,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- admuser@example.net using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.077840,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [Kerberos KDC,ENC-TS Pre-authentication] user [(null)]\[admuser@example.net] at [Tue, 04 Oct 2022 12:11:58.077747 CEST] with [aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [(null)] remote host [ipv4:172.27.2.58:50125] became [EXAMPLE]\[admuser] [S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1104]. local host [NULL] 
  {"timestamp": "2022-10-04T12:11:58.086113+0200", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "c61be2b0d84a3e12", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": null, "remoteAddress": "ipv4:172.27.2.58:50125", "serviceDescription": "Kerberos KDC", "authDescription": "ENC-TS Pre-authentication", "clientDomain": null, "clientAccount": "admuser@example.net", "workstation": null, "becameAccount": "admuser", "becameDomain": "EXAMPLE", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1104", "mappedAccount": "admuser", "mappedDomain": "EXAMPLE", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96", "duration": 31663}}
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.160727,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ authtime: 2022-10-04T12:11:58 starttime: unset endtime: 2022-10-04T22:11:58 renew till: 2022-10-11T12:11:58
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.161033,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, arcfour-hmac-md5, 24, -135, 3, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.161206,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Requested flags: renewable-ok, canonicalize, renewable, forwardable
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.165799,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.178036,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to verify authenticator checksum: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type rsa-md5, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.178282,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed parsing TGS-REQ from ipv4:172.27.2.58:50126
```

As you can see, the authentication here is reported to be successful. So far it's the same issue as [here](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1065/windows-client-unable-join-domain-samba-4-domain-controller-logon-failure-unknown-user-name), so I tried the following commands:

```
 root@SMBDC1:~# host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.example.net
    _ldap._tcp.example.net has SRV record 0 100 389 smbdc1.example.net.
 root@SMBDC1:~# host -t SRV _kerebros._udp.example.net
    Host _kerebros._udp.example.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
 root@SMBDC1:~# host -t A focal.exapmle.net
    Host focal.example.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
    
 root@SMBDC1:~# dig -t SRV _kerebros._udp.frankini.net
    
    ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> -t SRV _kerebros._udp.frankini.net
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 138
    ;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
    
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;_kerebros._udp.frankini.net.   IN      SRV
    
    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    frankini.net.           3600    IN      SOA        
    smbdc1.frankini.net. hostmaster.        frankini.net. 55 900 600 86400 3600
    
    ;; Query time: 3 msec
    ;; SERVER: 172.27.1.1#53(172.27.1.1)
    ;; WHEN: Fri Oct 07 21:44:12 CEST 2022
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 99
```

This originally worked but now i get "**Host not found**"... what could have changed?

*My setup*

```
router:     172.27.0.1
smbdc:      172.27.1.1
dns:        172.27.1.2

dhcp range: 172.27.2.2 - 172.27.2.254

Samba runs on an Orange Pi Zero and I connect to it through Putty and FileZilla

I route communication between the xxx.xxx.0.xxx, xxx.xxx.1.xxx and xxx.xxx.2.xxx ip ranges and set the network mask to be 255.255.0.0
```

*System*

```
 OS:    Armbian 22.05.3 Focal with Linux 5.15.48-sunxi
 SAMBA: Samba version 4.13.17-Ubuntu
```

*smb.conf*

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    dns forwarder = 172.27.1.2
    netbios name = SMBDC1
    realm = EXAMPLE.NET
    server role = active directory domain controller
    workgroup = EXAMPLE
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
    host msdfs = yes
    log level = 3

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/example.net/scripts
    read only = No
```

**UPDATE:**

I made an image of the disk as a backup, then did a bunch of tests with no success. so I finally reverted the image to the disk as it was, and now suddenly these comands work:

```
root@SMBDC1:~# host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.example.net
    _ldap._tcp.example.net has SRV record 0 100 389 smbdc1.example.net.
root@SMBDC1:~# host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.example.net
    _kerberos._udp.example.net has SRV record 0 100 88 smbdc1.example.net.
root@SMBDC1:~# host -t A SMBDC1.example.net
    SMBDC1.example.net has address 172.27.1.4
```

So the situation now is as follows:

I added the computer "*TESTING-W11*" to the domain with my domain admin user, not with 'administrator'. It works only if i do "user@example.net" and not "user", which used to work before. and if someone asks, yes I also tried with administrator and it only work as "administrator@example.com"

after the computer rebooted I tried to login but it says wrong user or password.

this is the log file of login attempt:

```
[2022/10/12 19:39:25.980185,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50574 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.008882,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.009229,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.009433,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.009709,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: No preauth found, returning PREAUTH-REQUIRED -- user2@EXAMPLE
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.013190,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.024021,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50575 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.051743,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: encrypted-timestamp, 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.052093,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.052302,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.052948,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- user2@EXAMPLE using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.053349,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [Kerberos KDC,ENC-TS Pre-authentication] user [(null)]\ [user2@EXAMPLE] at [Wed, 12 Oct 2022 19:39:26.053205 CEST] with [aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [(null)] remote host [ipv4:172.27.2.26:50575] became [EXAMPLE]\[user2] [S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105]. local host [NULL] 
  {"timestamp": "2022-10-12T19:39:26.053767+0200", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "d3433331ec6a5bf7", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": null, "remoteAddress": "ipv4:172.27.2.26:50575", "serviceDescription": "Kerberos KDC", "authDescription": "ENC-TS Pre-authentication", "clientDomain": null, "clientAccount": "user2@EXAMPLE", "workstation": null, "becameAccount": "user2", "becameDomain": "EXAMPLE", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105", "mappedAccount": "user2", "mappedDomain": "EXAMPLE", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96", "duration": 30203}}
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.089947,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ authtime: 2022-10-12T19:39:26 starttime: unset endtime: 2022-10-13T05:39:26 renew till: 2022-10-19T19:39:26
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.090338,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, arcfour-hmac-md5, 24, -135, 3, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.090474,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Requested flags: renewable-ok, canonicalize, renewable, forwardable
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.097520,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.106943,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to verify authenticator checksum: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type rsa-md5, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.107170,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed parsing TGS-REQ from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50576
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.110456,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.114239,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE.NET from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50577 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.127198,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.127410,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.127580,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.127768,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: No preauth found, returning PREAUTH-REQUIRED -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.130816,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.140450,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE.NET from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50578 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.152897,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: encrypted-timestamp, 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.153102,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.153210,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.153583,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.153816,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [Kerberos KDC,ENC-TS Pre-authentication] user [(null)]\[user2@EXAMPLE.NET] at [Wed, 12 Oct 2022 19:39:26.153732 CEST] with [aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [(null)] remote host [ipv4:172.27.2.26:50578] became [EXAMPLE]\[user2] [S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105]. local host [NULL]
  {"timestamp": "2022-10-12T19:39:26.154039+0200", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "869dfe1fc68f82a8", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": null, "remoteAddress": "ipv4:172.27.2.26:50578", "serviceDescription": "Kerberos KDC", "authDescription": "ENC-TS Pre-authentication", "clientDomain": null, "clientAccount": "user2@EXAMPLE.NET", "workstation": null, "becameAccount": "user2", "becameDomain": "EXAMPLE", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105", "mappedAccount": "user2", "mappedDomain": "EXAMPLE", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96", "duration": 13913}}
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.182189,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ authtime: 2022-10-12T19:39:26 starttime: unset endtime: 2022-10-13T05:39:26 renew till: 2022-10-19T19:39:26
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.182483,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, arcfour-hmac-md5, 24, -135, 3, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.182612,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Requested flags: renewable-ok, canonicalize, renewable, forwardable
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.187831,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.197162,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to verify authenticator checksum: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type rsa-md5, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.197385,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed parsing TGS-REQ from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50579
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.202216,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.206268,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE.NET from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50580 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.218896,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.219112,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.219220,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.219367,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: No preauth found, returning PREAUTH-REQUIRED -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.226212,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.236585,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE.NET from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50581 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.249060,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: encrypted-timestamp, 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.249272,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.249377,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.249842,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.250084,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [Kerberos KDC,ENC-TS Pre-authentication] user [(null)]\[user2@EXAMPLE.NET] at [Wed, 12 Oct 2022 19:39:26.250002 CEST] with [aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [(null)] remote host [ipv4:172.27.2.26:50581] became [EXAMPLE]\[user2] [S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105]. local host [NULL] 
  {"timestamp": "2022-10-12T19:39:26.250309+0200", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "b111aea5f91526ac", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": null, "remoteAddress": "ipv4:172.27.2.26:50581", "serviceDescription": "Kerberos KDC", "authDescription": "ENC-TS Pre-authentication", "clientDomain": null, "clientAccount": "user2@EXAMPLE.NET", "workstation": null, "becameAccount": "user2", "becameDomain": "EXAMPLE", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105", "mappedAccount": "user2", "mappedDomain": "EXAMPLE", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96", "duration": 13999}}
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.278425,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ authtime: 2022-10-12T19:39:26 starttime: unset endtime: 2022-10-13T05:39:26 renew till: 2022-10-19T19:39:26
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.278721,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, arcfour-hmac-md5, 24, -135, 3, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.278850,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Requested flags: renewable-ok, canonicalize, renewable, forwardable
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.284069,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.293333,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to verify authenticator checksum: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type rsa-md5, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.293567,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed parsing TGS-REQ from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50582
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.297119,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.301280,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE.NET from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50583 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.314043,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.314253,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.314361,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.314507,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: No preauth found, returning PREAUTH-REQUIRED -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.317995,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.328064,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ user2@EXAMPLE.NET from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50584 for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.340620,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: encrypted-timestamp, 128
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.340832,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.340934,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.341304,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- user2@EXAMPLE.NET using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.341534,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [Kerberos KDC,ENC-TS Pre-authentication] user [(null)]\[user2@EXAMPLE.NET] at [Wed, 12 Oct 2022 19:39:26.341453 CEST] with [aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [(null)] remote host [ipv4:172.27.2.26:50584] became [EXAMPLE]\[user2] [S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105]. local host [NULL] 
  {"timestamp": "2022-10-12T19:39:26.341761+0200", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "4baa7d35daccf446", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": null, "remoteAddress": "ipv4:172.27.2.26:50584", "serviceDescription": "Kerberos KDC", "authDescription": "ENC-TS Pre-authentication", "clientDomain": null, "clientAccount": "user2@EXAMPLE.NET", "workstation": null, "becameAccount": "user2", "becameDomain": "EXAMPLE", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1105", "mappedAccount": "user2", "mappedDomain": "EXAMPLE", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96", "duration": 13987}}
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.369985,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ authtime: 2022-10-12T19:39:26 starttime: unset endtime: 2022-10-13T05:39:26 renew till: 2022-10-19T19:39:26
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.370274,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, arcfour-hmac-md5, 24, -135, 3, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.370405,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Requested flags: renewable-ok, canonicalize, renewable, forwardable
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.375775,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.385121,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to verify authenticator checksum: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type rsa-md5, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.385343,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed parsing TGS-REQ from ipv4:172.27.2.26:50585
[2022/10/12 19:39:26.388686,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
```

is there something wrong in the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this deja-vue ? I thought I answered this once, either you are fat fingering the typing or you are spelling kerberos and example wrong.
Your main problem is that YOU CANNOT JOIN A COMPUTER TO A SAMBA DOMAIN UNLESS YOU USE 'Administrator'. Windows allows any tom, dick or harry to join computers, but Samba doesn't. This really isn't the place to discuss this, I suggest you go here:
https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/samba

Subscribe to the samba mailing list and come and discuss it with me there.

Answer (score 0):

After being redirected [here](https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/samba) by [Rowland](https://serverfault.com/a/1112900/987417), I was able to reach someone that found the problem instantly!

Windows11 version 22H2 is not compatible with Samba 4.15 and I'm now trying to upgrade to Samba 4.16 to fix it!

...it just happened that all the PCs I was trying to join to the domain were all fresh Win11 installs and so I never caught the discrepency (still works on older versions of windows).